# Event is not broadcasting in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I am using laravel pusher and echo to broadcast an event but it doesn't happening.

```
class NewOrderAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('public-test-channel');
    }
}
```

Here is the code where broadcasting should be received.

```
listen(){
  console.log("Listening...");
  Echo.channel('public-test-channel')
        .listen('NewOrderAdded', (e) => {
          console.log("Event received");
        });
}
```

Here is bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: 'xxxxxxxx',
        cluster: 'ap1',
        encrypted: true
    });
```

Controller class

```
  public function create(Request $request){
    $order = new Order([
      'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
      'person_id' => json_encode($request->get('person_id')),
      'date_of_booking' => $request->get('date_of_booking'),
      'total_order_price' =>$request->get('total_order_price'),
      'ticket_id' => json_encode($request->get('ticket_id')),
      'timeslot' => $request->get('timeslot'),
      'status' => 'pending',
      'add_on_id' => json_encode($request->get('add_on_id'))
    ]);
    $order->save();
    event(new NewOrderAdded());
    return response()->json(array('order_id'=>$order->id));
  }
```

I have also attached log image from pusher.[image]
What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the content of your logs?

Comment: And for that matter your .env (did you clear your config cache after any changes)

Comment: @milo526, i am not sure what do you mean. I check the console and there isn't any error.

Comment: There is a log file in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @milo526, Here is the log file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3hSlw1AYdKYS1hLTWNxLUs4Ync

Comment: Is there any one who can suggest solution?